# InvalidKeyException: Invalid key format java

Tags: java, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, public-key

I am trying to retrieve the public key from Vault. It is stored as secret.

I am trying to convert the string retrieved to a PUBLIC KEY to verify the signature.

Sample public key string looks like this

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBITANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ4AMIIBCQKCAQBWeqVZ8Ub/o4VQ8nnm888B
> /Ydqv2IN5bObxupZ7njMKuT/WPgwlK8+Wc0Xjhy82E51XW6E4/0um8sIQ1cxvoSO
> QsrfkRagD+O9OrjQbb2TqrilDDhFx9EGjXuZpR3brDUufCG6SkypqiKSaMuoVoax
> c82TZ1uAIp5OSroWt1IdUkvam24X/7zDIf1l8XWCmbfCDrBb73hBYA4MgTjsSckC
> 5nz+GLcWTfz0wze4lwHCi1KYFv+1+WcYHWPLbqLtc8nzVqkuP5Ne/9HAFkaEAIw5
> fKLccksaT/TLyIcrALcfuABlgX1yeBulVcbTAp+WiYRvo9+FKK23pbwkh+uy0tq1
> AgMBAAE=
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

I have added the same in my secret value and there is no formatting.

However with the below code I am facing error InvalidKeyException: INVALID KEY FORMAT in the line

```
 PublicKey publicKey = fact.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
```

Here is the code:

```
            String publicKeyAsString = secretClient.getSecret("key-name").getValue();
    
            byte[] keyContentAsBytes = publicKeyAsString.getBytes();
    
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyContentAsBytes);
            PublicKey publicKey = fact.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
```

Edited with stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:386) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:401) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:122) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:330) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:235) ~[?:?]
```

EDIT: PUBLIC KEY for testing:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBITANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ4AMIIBCQKCAQBWeqVZ8Ub/o4VQ8nnm888B
> /Ydqv2IN5bObxupZ7njMKuT/WPgwlK8+Wc0Xjhy82E51XW6E4/0um8sIQ1cxvoSO
> QsrfkRagD+O9OrjQbb2TqrilDDhFx9EGjXuZpR3brDUufCG6SkypqiKSaMuoVoax
> c82TZ1uAIp5OSroWt1IdUkvam24X/7zDIf1l8XWCmbfCDrBb73hBYA4MgTjsSckC
> 5nz+GLcWTfz0wze4lwHCi1KYFv+1+WcYHWPLbqLtc8nzVqkuP5Ne/9HAFkaEAIw5
> fKLccksaT/TLyIcrALcfuABlgX1yeBulVcbTAp+WiYRvo9+FKK23pbwkh+uy0tq1
> AgMBAAE=
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

The value of **PublicKeyAsString** looks like below:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBITANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ4AMIIBCQKCAQBWeqVZ8Ub/o4VQ8nnm888B
> /Ydqv2IN5bObxupZ7njMKuT/WPgwlK8+Wc0Xjhy82E51XW6E4/0um8sIQ1cxvoSO
> QsrfkRagD+O9OrjQbb2TqrilDDhFx9EGjXuZpR3brDUufCG6SkypqiKSaMuoVoax
> c82TZ1uAIp5OSroWt1IdUkvam24X/7zDIf1l8XWCmbfCDrBb73hBYA4MgTjsSckC
> 5nz+GLcWTfz0wze4lwHCi1KYFv+1+WcYHWPLbqLtc8nzVqkuP5Ne/9HAFkaEAIw5
> fKLccksaT/TLyIcrALcfuABlgX1yeBulVcbTAp+WiYRvo9+FKK23pbwkh+uy0tq1
> AgMBAAE= -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Initially I thought that your problem had to do with the kind of information returned by the Azure KeyVault Secret API, usually encoded as base 64.

In that case, you nee to perform a proper base 64 decoding before attempting to perform the actual key material processing:

```java
String publicKeyAsString = secretClient.getSecret("key-name").getValue();
    
byte[] keyContentAsBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyAsString);
```

But it seems that the Azure client is providing you the information as plain text.

In this case, the secret is a pem encoded public key.

The standard `KeyFactory` will not allow you to process the returned information out of the box, but yes with slight modifications. For example, try the following:

```java
// Actually
// String publicKeyAsString = secretClient.getSecret("key-name").getValue();

String publicKeyAsString =
    "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
    "MIIBITANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ4AMIIBCQKCAQBWeqVZ8Ub/o4VQ8nnm888B\n" +
    "/Ydqv2IN5bObxupZ7njMKuT/WPgwlK8+Wc0Xjhy82E51XW6E4/0um8sIQ1cxvoSO\n" +
    "QsrfkRagD+O9OrjQbb2TqrilDDhFx9EGjXuZpR3brDUufCG6SkypqiKSaMuoVoax\n" +
    "c82TZ1uAIp5OSroWt1IdUkvam24X/7zDIf1l8XWCmbfCDrBb73hBYA4MgTjsSckC\n" +
    "5nz+GLcWTfz0wze4lwHCi1KYFv+1+WcYHWPLbqLtc8nzVqkuP5Ne/9HAFkaEAIw5\n" +
    "fKLccksaT/TLyIcrALcfuABlgX1yeBulVcbTAp+WiYRvo9+FKK23pbwkh+uy0tq1\n" +
    "AgMBAAE=\n" +
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

String publicKeyPem = publicKeyAsString
    .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
    .replaceAll("\\n", "")
    .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");

byte[] keyContentAsBytes =  Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPem);

try {
  KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
  X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyContentAsBytes);
  PublicKey publicKey = fact.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
  System.out.println(publicKey);
}catch (Throwable t) {
  t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or better, use BouncyCastle `PemReader` for this task:

```java
try (
    Reader reader = new StringReader(publicKeyAsString);
    PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(reader)
) {
  KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
  PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
  byte[] keyContentAsBytesFromBC = pemObject.getContent();
  X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyContentAsBytesFromBC);
  PublicKey publicKey = fact.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
  System.out.println(publicKey);
} catch (Throwable t) {
  t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please, be aware that I included several carriage returns in the definition of the variable `publicKeyAsString`, they were necessary in order to allow the program process the information.

Please, verify that Azure is returning the pem encoded key in a similar way: if it is not the case, it could be very likely the reason of the problem.

Also, pay attention in the fact that Azure KeyVault is returning the secret as you uploaded it: maybe the problem is there. Please, try the following instead:

```java
PublicKey publicKey = ...
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(writer);
pemWriter.writeObject(
  new PemObject("PUBLIC KEY", publicKey.getEncoded())
);
pemWriter.flush();
pemWriter.close();
String publicKeyAsString = writer.toString();
// Upload to Azure KeyVault
```

Comment: I tried to do the same and I am getting illegal base 64 charachter 29 exception

Comment: It is very strange @Rohi, it should work without any problem. Please, can you debug the value returned by `secretClient.getSecret("key-name").getValue()` and see if something is wrong with it? Does it print a right base 64 string?

Comment: Could you tell me how can I validate that it is a right base 64 string ?

Comment: First, were you able to print the value? Does it looks like a valid base 64 encoding? Pease, can you tell me what OS are you using?

Comment: yes I Can print the value. I am using windows

Comment: And, it looks like a valid base 64 encoding information?

Comment: I am checking that

Comment: I did validate if the string is base 64 or not, and unfortunately it is not

Comment: Ok @Rohi. By the way, in do not use windows in my day to day work, but I think you can decode a base64 encoded string either saving the information to a file and the apply something like `certutil -decode data.b64 data.txt` from the command line, or with Power shell, with something like this, `$ENCODED = "AFSF... your value"
$DECODED = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($ENCODED))
Write-Output $DECODED`

Comment: @Rohi, but you are using Azure KeyVault and the SDK libraries provided by Microsoft, aren't you?

Comment: Yes I am using keyvault.So the above method to do it a text file doesnt work . I need to do that in code itself.

Comment: Of course @Rohi, I understand, I proposed the command line options just to verify that the information is base 64 encoded

Comment: Oh, Yeah thank you. I wil do that as well . currently I checked with regexpattern matching

Comment: If you are using KeyVault, the value returned by the secret should be base 64 encoded. At least, it looks like base 64 encoded information? I mean, is it possible that only some chars are incorrect? Please, can you provide your stack trace?

Comment: I dont think so, I tried to save a public key in the key vault secret. I dont think there should be something wrong with that

Comment: Please, can you provide some text, not all the text, as they are returned by `secretClient.getSecret("key-name").getValue()` and the stack trace of the error?

Comment: I have provided it in the description above and edited with the stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you very much Please, see my update. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Rohi, please, see the updated content of the answer, I forgot that you of course need to decode also the text within the `----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `----END PUBLIC KEY-----` boundaries :(: `byte[] keyContentAsBytes =  Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPem);`

Comment: However the base64.getDecode.decode(); throws the exception and I am not able to proceed further

Comment: Do you mean the first or the second one? Sorry, when I saw the stack trace I thought that tit was raised after processing the information returned by Azure. Do you follow the examples? Does the variable `publicKeyPem` look like it should be? It should be great if you can include, even in a comment, a small fragment of the base 64 text that is causing the problem and the stack trace of `Base64.getDecoder().decode(...)`

Comment: I am trying to follow the second example with the bouncyCastle. and in the second line there is this base64.getdecoder.decode() method where the exception is already thrown. So I could not proceed further to look into the issue

Comment: I see. Please, can include in a comment a small fragment of the text that is causing the problem, the value obtained from `secretClient.getSecret("key-name").getValue()`?

Comment: @Rohi, please, can you try the BouncyCastle approach but without decoding? I mean, substitute the line `byte[] pemContentAsBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyAsString);` by `byte[] pemContentAsBytes = publicKeyAsString.getBytes();`. You are getting the right value for the secret without decoding indeed

Comment: the pemObject throws a null pointer exception in line pemobject.getcontent

Comment: This is probably because pemobject is not resolved correctly. Please, can you try the first and simpler approach? Please, try with the aforementioned change `byte[] pemContentAsBytes = publicKeyAsString.getBytes();`

Comment: I tried that and got IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 charachter 20

Comment: I see @Rohi. Is the value you indicated for the variable `publickeyAsAString` the actual one? I mean, can I use it for testing?

Comment: I dont think you could use that for testing, I modified it. I can provide something similar for testing

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate that. Yes, please, never post something that is actually valuable in the answer. I must leave now, but I will review the example later.

Comment: I have edited the question with a public key that could be used for testing and the value that is retrieved from Vault

Comment: Thank you very much @Rohi. I updated my answer. In fact, all seems to be fine, I think the only problem are the base 64 encoding of the public key, it seems to be incorrect. Maybe you uploading the key with the wrong format? Please, see the answer. I tested the provided code and it works properly.

Comment: Just one more question .Could a public key be PKC8Encoded format ?

Comment: Hi @Rohi. Were you able to solve the problem? Regarding your question, AFAIK no, only private keys can be stored in PKCS#8 format.

Comment: No, I am not able to . But if I provide it as string in my code, then the code helps I can do it. However, the secret returned from vault , is somehow badly formatted or not pem encoded.

Comment: Assuming the above public key , how would you provide it as a secret value in Vault ?

Comment: I am going to mark your solution as answered :) Since the issue is from the value returned from Vault. Any input on that also would be helpful .

Comment: Thank you very much @Rohi ;). Please, see the update, I hope it helps.

Comment: let me try that. IF i understood that correctly, that means, I will use the code to get the publickey as a string and upload it to my azure vault right ?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea @Rohi